# C# combining multiple filter bool methods into one

Tags: c#, filter, boolean

I've created four methods to get working filter based on multiple parameters:

```cs
bool FilterAreas(AreaPlaceCoordinate apc)
{
            if (!AreaHash.Any())
            {
                return true;
            }
            foreach (var _ in AreaHash.Where(h => apc.AreaName.Contains(h, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Select(h => new { }))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
}
bool FilterPlaces(AreaPlaceCoordinate apc)
{
            if (!PlaceHash.Any())
            {
                return true;
            }
            foreach (var _ in PlaceHash.Where(h => apc.PlaceName.Contains(h, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Select(h => new { }))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
}
bool FilterCoordinates(AreaPlaceCoordinate apc)
{
            if (!CoordinateHash.Any())
            {
                return true;
            }
            foreach (var _ in CoordinateHash.Where(h => apc.CoordinateName.Contains(h, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Select(h => new { }))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
}
bool Filter(AreaPlaceCoordinate apc)
{
  return FilterCoordinates(apc)&&FilterPlaces(apc)&& FilterAreas(apc);
}
```

I think it could be done with one method, but despite of many attempts I don't know how to handle it. Those are my objects used in example:

```cs
//Hash
private IEnumerable<string> PlaceHash { get; set; } = new HashSet<string>() { };
private IEnumerable<string> AreaHash { get; set; } = new HashSet<string>() { };
private IEnumerable<string> CoordinateHash { get; set; } = new HashSet<string>() { };
```

```cs
public class AreaPlaceCoordinate
    {
        public int CoordinateId { get; set; }
        public string CoordinateName { get; set; }
        public int AreaId { get; set; }
        public int PlaceId { get; set; }
        public string AreaName { get; set; }
        public string PlaceName { get; set; }
    }
```

I would appreciate any ideas

### Update

Thank you, @Abanslash!
I also added string text filter and ended with code like this:

```cs
 private string searchString1 = "";
        static bool FilterHash<T>(IEnumerable<string> list, T viewModel, Func<string, bool> p)
        {
            if (!list.Any())
            {
                return true;
            }
            return list.Any(p);
        }
        public bool TestFilter(AreaPlaceCoordinate apc)
        {
            bool textEmpty = (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString1));
            List<string> names = new() { apc.AreaName, apc.PlaceName, apc.CoordinateName };
            bool filterText = textEmpty ? true : names.Any(n => n.Contains(searchString1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            bool areaSelector(string str) => apc.AreaName.Contains(str);
            bool coordinateSelector(string str) => apc.CoordinateName.Contains(str);
            bool placeSelector(string str) => apc.PlaceName.Contains(str);
            return FilterHash(AreaHash, apc, areaSelector) && FilterHash(CoordinateHash, apc, coordinateSelector) && FilterHash(PlaceHash, apc, placeSelector) && filterText;
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using a `foreach` with `Select( _ => new {} )` instead of just `.Any()`?

Comment: new{ } is result of auto conversion in Visual Studio, I just left it like that temporary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is to use are Predicates, you can have a generic method where you also pass the predicate.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=net-6.0

If you are not very familiar with generic you can also specify the base type of the generic using where.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint

Answer (score 0):

In case you were not able to solve your issue with my previous comment here you go:

```
        bool Filter<T>(IEnumerable<string> list, T apc, Func<string, bool> p)
        {
            if (!list.Any())
            {
                return true;
            }
            return list.Any(p);
        }

        public void testFilter()
        {
            AreaPlaceCoordinate coord = new AreaPlaceCoordinate();
            Func<string, bool> selector = str => coord.AreaName.Contains(str);
            this.Filter(PlaceHash, coord, selector);
        }
```

You will have to modify a little bit for what you want to achieve and create the different selectors for your different filters.